# Instantiating a Class in the Custom Module

Tags: 8

I am trying to build a custom module to process credit card payments through a PHP Rest Client created by the credit card processing vendor.  Here is that Rest Client:

```
<?php
/**
* CardConnect PHP REST Client Library
* Version: 1.0
Copyright 2014, CardConnect (http://www.cardconnect.com)

Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH
REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT,
INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM
LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR
OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR
PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
*/

require_once 'pest/PestJSON.php';
class CardConnectRestClient {
    private $url = "";
    private $user = "";
    private $password = "";

    private $OP_POST   = "POST";
    private $OP_PUT    = "PUT";
    private $OP_GET    = "GET";
    private $OP_DELETE = "DELETE";

    private $ENDPOINT_AUTH       = "auth";
    private $ENDPOINT_CAPTURE    = "capture";
    private $ENDPOINT_VOID       = "void";
    private $ENDPOINT_REFUND     = "refund";
    private $ENDPOINT_INQUIRE    = "inquire";
    private $ENDPOINT_SETTLESTAT = "settlestat";
    private $ENDPOINT_DEPOSIT    = "deposit";
    private $ENDPOINT_PROFILE    = "profile";

    private $USER_AGENT     = "CardConnectRestClient-PHP";
    private $CLIENT_VERSION = "1.0";


    /**
    * Constructor to create a new CardConnectRestClient object
    *
    * @param string $ccurl CardConnect REST URL (https://sitename.cardconnect.com:6443/cardconnect/rest/)
    * @param string $user Username
    * @param string $pass Password
    */
    public function __construct($ccurl, $user, $pass) {
        if (self::isEmpty($ccurl)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("url parameter is required");
        if (self::isEmpty($user)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("username parameter is required");
        if (self::isEmpty($pass)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("password parameter is required");

        if (!self::endsWith($ccurl, "/")) $ccurl .= "/";
        
        $this->url = $ccurl;
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    }

    /**
    * Sends an Authorize Transaction request via REST
    *
    * @param array $request Array representing an authorization request
    * @return array Array representing an authorization response
    */
    public function authorizeTransaction($request) {
        return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_AUTH, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
    }


    /**
    * Sends a Capture Transaction request via REST
    *
    * @param array $request Array representing a capture request
    * @return array Array representing a capture response
    */
    public function captureTransaction($request) {
        return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_CAPTURE, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Sends a Void Transaction request via REST
    *
    * @param array $request Array representing a void request
    * @return array Array representing a void response
    */
    public function voidTransaction($request) {
        return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_VOID, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Sends a Refund Transaction request via REST
    *
    * @param array $request Array representing a refund request
    * @return array Array representing a refund response
    */
    public function refundTransaction($request) {
        return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_REFUND, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Sends an Inquire Transaction request via REST
    *
    * @param string $merchid Merchant ID
    * @param string $retref RetRef from previous authorization/capture response 
    * @return array Array representing an inquire response
    */
    public function inquireTransaction($merchid, $retref) {
        if (self::isEmpty($merchid)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: merchid");
        if (self::isEmpty($retref)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: retref");
        
        $url = $this->ENDPOINT_INQUIRE . "/" . $retref . "/" . $merchid;
        return self::send($url, $this->OP_GET, null);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Sends a Settlement Status request via REST
    *
    * @param string $merchid Merchant ID
    * @param string $date Settlement Date
    * @return array Array representing the requested settlement status
    */
    public function settlementStatus($merchid = "", $date = "") {
        if ((!self::isEmpty($merchid) && self::isEmpty($date)) || (self::isEmpty($merchid) && !self::isEmpty($date))) 
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Both merchid and date parameters are required, or neither");
        
        $url;
        if (self::isEmpty($merchid) || self::isEmpty($date)) {
            $url = $this->ENDPOINT_SETTLESTAT;
        } else {
            $url = $this->ENDPOINT_SETTLESTAT . "?date=" . $date . "&merchid=" . $merchid;
        }
        
        return self::send($url, $this->OP_GET, null);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Sends a Deposit Status request via REST
    *
    * @param string $merchid Merchant ID
    * @param string $date Deposit Date
    * @return array Array representing the requested deposit status
    */
    public function depositStatus($merchid = "", $date = "") {
        if ((!self::isEmpty($merchid) && self::isEmpty($date)) || (self::isEmpty($merchid) && !self::isEmpty($date)))
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Both merchid and date parameters are required, or neither");
        
        $url;
        if (self::isEmpty($merchid) || self::isEmpty($date)) {
            $url = $this->ENDPOINT_DEPOSIT;
        } else {
            $url = $this->ENDPOINT_DEPOSIT . "?merchid=" . $merchid . "&date=" . $date;
        }
        return self::send($url, $this->OP_GET, null);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Retrieves the specified profile via REST
    *
    * @param string $profileid Profile ID
    * @param string $accountid Optional Account ID
    * @param string $merchid Merchant ID
    * @return array Array representing the retrieved profile
    */
    public function profileGet($profileid, $accountid = "", $merchid) {
        if (self::isEmpty($profileid)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: profileid");
        if (self::isEmpty($merchid)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: merchid");
        
        $url = $this->ENDPOINT_PROFILE . "/" . $profileid . "/" . $accountid . "/" . $merchid;
        return self::send($url, $this->OP_GET, null);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Deletes the specified profile via REST
    *
    * @param string $profileid Profile ID
    * @param string $accountid Optional Account ID
    * @param string $merchid Merchant ID
    * @return array Array representing the results of the profile deletion
    */
    public function profileDelete($profileid, $accountid = "", $merchid) {
        if (self::isEmpty($profileid)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: profileid");
        if (self::isEmpty($merchid)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing required parameter: merchid");
        
        $url = $this->ENDPOINT_PROFILE . "/" . $profileid . "/" . $accountid . "/" . $merchid;
        return self::send($url, $this->OP_DELETE, null);
    }
    
    
    /**
    * Creates or updates a profile via REST
    *
    * @param array $request Array representing the Profile create/update request
    * @return array Array representing the profile creation
    */
    public function profileCreate($request) {
        return self::send($this->ENDPOINT_PROFILE, $this->OP_PUT, $request);
    }
    
    
    // Returns true if a string is null or empty string
    static function isEmpty($s) {
        if (is_null($s)) return true;
        if (strlen($s) <= 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    // Checks the last character of a string
    static function endsWith($s, $char) {
        return $char === "" || substr($s, -strlen($char)) === $char;
    }

    // Private method for sending HTTP REST request to CardConnect
    private function send($endpoint, $operation, $request) {
        $pest = new PestJSON($this->url);
        $pest->setupAuth($this->username, $this->password);
        $pest->curl_opts[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = false; // Not supported on hosts running safe_mode!
        $pest->curl_opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        $pest->curl_opts[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $this->USER_AGENT . " (v" . $this->CLIENT_VERSION . ")";

        $response = ""; 
        try {           
            // Send request to rest service
            switch ($operation) {
                case ($this->OP_PUT):
                    $response = $pest->put("/$endpoint", $request);
                    break;
                case ($this->OP_GET):
                    $response = $pest->get("/$endpoint", $request);
                    break;
                case ($this->OP_POST):
                    $response = $pest->post("/$endpoint", $request);
                    break;
                case ($this->OP_DELETE):
                    $response = $pest->delete("/$endpoint", $request);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Caught exception when sending request : " .  $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

?>
```

Here is my custom module:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\cc_processing_cardconnect\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandler\EmailWebformHandler;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Form submission handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "cc_processing_cardconnect",
 *   label = @Translation("CC Processing CardConnect"),
 *   category = @Translation("Webform Handler"),
 *   description = @Translation("Process credit card payemnt through CardConnect."),
 *   cardinality = 
 *       \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = 
 *    \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */

require_once 'CardConnectRestClient.php';

class CCProcessingCardConnectWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/

    // Username
        static $devUser = "testing";
        static $prodUser = "";
        
    // Password
        static $devPassword = "testing123";
        static $prodPassword = "";
        
    // Merchant ID
        static $devMID = '000000000000';
        static $prodMID = '';
        
    // Site's REST URL
        static $devURL = 'https://fts-uat.cardconnect.com/cardconnect/rest/';
        static $prodURL = '';
        
    // Environment (live or dev)
        static $env = 'dev';
            

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

       $form_id = 'webform_submission_' . $webform_submission->getWebform()->id() . '_form';
       //if($form_id == 'webform_submission_xxx_form') {
         $values = $webform_submission->getData();  
         /* Take the action based on the Webform submission values */   
       //}    
    }

    public function confirmForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
        $form_id = 'webform_submission_' . $webform_submission->getWebform()->id() . '_form';
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        
        // Variables
        if($env == 'dev'){
            $url = $this->$devURL;
            $user = $this->$devUser;
            $password = $this->$devPassword;
            $MID = $this->$devMID;
        }        
        else {            
            $url = $this->$prodURL;
            $user = $this->$prodUser;
            $password = $this->$prodPassword;
            $MID = $this->$prodMID;
        }
        
        $client = new CardConnectRestClient($url, $user, $password);

        $request = array(
            'merchid'   => $MID,
            'account'   => "4111111111111111",
            'expiry'    => "0922",
            'cvv2'      => "123",
            'amount'    => "999.99",
            'currency'  => "USD",
            'name'      => "Test User",
            'street'    => "Test Address",
            'city'      => "Test City",
            'region'    => "HI",
            'country'   => "US",
            'postal'    => "96822",
            'tokenize'  => "Y",
            'capture'   => "Y",
        );

        $response = $client->authorizeTransaction($request);
        $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1765 ]);
    }
}
?>
```

This line of code: **$client = new CardConnectRestClient($url, $user, $password);** throws this error when I test the form: **Fatal error: Cannot declare class CardConnectRestClient, because the name is already in use in D:\drupal\modules\custom\cc_processing_cardconnect\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\CardConnectRestClient.php on line 21**

What am I doing wrong in trying to instantiate the Rest Client class?  Does Drupal automatically instantiate the class for me when I require it above the class declaration?  I am pretty new to developing in Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use namespace (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to load your classes and avoid using `require_once()`

Place your `CardConnectRestClient` class in a `CardConnectRestClient.php` in a folder inside your module and declare the namespace accordingly, i.e.

Folder : `your_module/src/Librairies/Rest`

Namespace : `Drupal\your_module\Librairies\Rest;`

(the `src` folder is kind of the "root" namespace of your module)

in your `CCProcessingCardConnectWebformHandler` class, declare the dependency :(https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) with `use` instructions :

`use Drupal\your_module\Librairies\Rest\CardConnectRestClient;`

Then PHP will automatically load the file when you call the class on the line `$client = new CardConnectRestClient($url, $user, $password);`

And more importantly, it will do it only once.

You could do the same with the dependency `pest/PestJSON.php` hard-loaded in the `CardConnectRestClient` class.